# How do I add touch controls to an Object in libGDX?

Tags: java, android, libgdx

I'm making a balloon popping game for android in libGDX and I'm currently stuck on how to make the balloons pop when the user touches them. I tried using the touchDown() method,

```
b = new Balloon();
        b.addListener(
                new InputListener()
                {
                    public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
                    {
                        b.remove();
                        popped++;
                        return true;
                    }
                });
        mainStage.addActor(b);
    }
```

but it doesn't work. I need a way so that only the balloons that I touch get popped and the others don't.

p.s I'm still learing libGDX so I'm a pretty big noob at it.

Edit: The Balloon is an Actor, and I did set the InputProcessor as well. The touch thing works but it doesn't pop the balloon that I touch it only pops the balloons that spawn at the starting x-axis.

Comment: Have you using `Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(mainStage);` ?

Comment: Is the balloon even an actor?

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to set your stage as input processor with Gdx.input.setInputProcessor(mainStage)

Then you can just add a ClickListener where you override the clicked method like this:

```
b.addListener(new ClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void clicked(InputEvent event, float x, float y) {
        super.clicked(event, x, y);

        //YOUR_CODE
    }
});
```